# Want to concatenate the columns in table using for loop by taking the column name from the List

Tags: python, pandas

Want to concatenate the columns in table using For loop by taking the column name variables from the List item

When I do for loop to concatenate the columns in table, columns are not getting concatenated as expected.

[image]

```
KeyList = [ 'Employee #', 'ID5' ]

for x in range (0, len(KeyList)):
   dfSrcData["Keys"] = dfSrcData[KeyList[x]].apply(str)
   dfSrcData["Comkeys"] = dfSrcData["Keys"] + '-'


Print(dfSrcData["ComKeys"])

Expected Results should be
516-56
517-57
518-58
519-59
520-60
```

Comment: `df[KeyList].astype(str).apply('-'.join,1)`?

Comment: I'm trying using For loop but please suggest me if there is any better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
KeyList = [ 'Employee #', 'ID5' ]

dfSrcData["ComKeys"] = dfSrcData[KeyList].astype(str).add('-').sum(axis=1).str.strip('-')
```

*NOTE: Order of the KeyList matters here. Concatenation will be in the order of selection*

Comment: Thank you it works. I'm getting the concatenated value in decimals Example: 516-56.0 Don't want the decimal value.

Comment: Use `dfSrcData[KeyList].astype(int).astype(str).add('-').sum(axis=1).str.strip('-')` ?

Comment: I'm reading the data from excel as string but still I'm getting the output as 516-56.0  Is any way to avoid the decimal value

Comment: It didn't work getting the error message as " Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"

Comment: There are `NaN` values. See pandas `fillna` documentation. NaN values should have been fixed at start.

Comment: Thanks it worked. used below code to conver Nan values                                                                 values =  {}.fromkeys(KeyList, 0)
dfSrcDataActual=dfSrcData.fillna(value=values )

Comment: Thank you vishnudev. I'm just starting with pandas and python, could you please suggest what to learn to improve my skills towards career in data science

Answer (score 0):

Straight old addition also works:

```
dfSrcData["ComKeys"] = dfSrcData['Employee *'].astype(str) + '-' + dfSrcData['ID5'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to use the values dynamically from the list...don't want to hard code it.